# How do I pass a className to a image component in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-props

I am using gatsby-image and gatsby-source-filesytem I want the img tag (Logo component) when rendered as html to have a `className` of `logo` how do I go about doing this, gatsby-image docs say to pass it through props. I still don't quite understand react, so need help understanding here is my code.

`logo.js`

```
import React from "react"
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

/*
 * This component is built using `gatsby-image` to automatically serve optimized
 * images with lazy loading and reduced file sizes. The image is loaded using a
 * `StaticQuery`, which allows us to load the image from directly within this
 * component, rather than having to pass the image data down from pages.
 *
 * For more information, see the docs:
 * - `gatsby-image`: https://gatsby.app/gatsby-image
 * - `StaticQuery`: https://gatsby.app/staticquery
 */

const Image = () => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query {
        placeholderImage: file(relativePath: { eq: "riel-type.png" }) {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(maxWidth: 300) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => <Img fluid={data.placeholderImage.childImageSharp.fluid} />}
  />
)
export default Image
```

`index.js`

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Image from "../components/image"
import Logo from "../components/logo"
import SEO from "../components/seo"

const IndexPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <SEO title="Home" keywords={[`gatsby`, `application`, `react`]} />
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-4">
        <Logo />
      </div>
    </div>
  </Layout>
)

export default IndexPage
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> gatsby-image docs say to pass it through props

Means that you can add any property you want inside the `Img` tag. Because of some internal restriction you have to use the JavaScript name attribute and not the HTML one (ie `className` instead of `class`)

So :

```
render={data => <Img fluid={data.placeholderImage.childImageSharp.fluid} className="logo" />}
```